Compose project crash when adding the compose animation library with shared element transition
I'm using compose version compose-bom 2023.03.00 and when I try to add the latest compose animation module (1.7.0-alpha07) with shared elements update, the app crashes on launch with error showing

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method restrictedConstraints-xF2OJ5Q$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/unit/Constraints$Companion;IIIIZILjava/lang/Object;)J in class Landroidx/compose/ui/unit/Constraints$Companion; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion' appears in /data/app/com.xx.xxxx-55o2y0IBA6N3Qr0mj4DgbQ==/base.apk
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurementHelper.measureWithoutPlacing-EkL-Y(RowColumnMeasurementHelper.kt:187)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:69)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:135)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:838)

Just adding the dependency itself causes the crash (without adding any ShareElementsLayout etc).
IN a sample app, it works fine. Is it due to any compatibility issues with other compose libraries ? How can I find the issue due to incompatibility issues ?
I tried matching the sample app's dependency versions (1.7.0-beta01 also has issues), but there are other libraries also found in our main app.
It also created the same crash.

Most probably an incompatibility with differing compose versions. Since you didn't specify which dependency and which version you use (there are different latest versions, like stable/alpha) we cannot really tell. Can you be more specific?

@Leviathan Sorry. Updated with versions.

Please provide a [mre]. "Just adding the dependency" works fine. What else must be done to reproduce the problem?

@Leviathan I'll try and update if possible.

If you are using the BOM, it's best to let the BOM pick the correct version for you. If you need pre-release features you could try - https://github.com/chrisbanes/compose-bom

Adding the dependency implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.7.0-beta01") along with the compose-animation 1.7.0 beta01, which seems to make the project run without any issues.
I'm still not sure about this particular dependency. I've tried to add the material:material library in the bom.
But the project by philip lackner - https://github.com/philipplackner/SharedElementTransitionCompose/blob/master/gradle/libs.versions.toml
uses a combination of stable bom with compose animation alpha, which seems to be working fine. Maybe there is some extra dependencies in my project which contributes this issue.
